# PHP/MySQL Stored procedure issue

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to add to my SQL database using a stored procedure, this procedure should add a unique_id, name, password and email address.

I am using the following code:

```
    //Enter the valid data into the database
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $encrypted_password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);

    $insertUser = mysqli_query($conn, "Call userInsert('$uuid', '$username','$encrypted_password', '$email')"); 

        if(! $insertUser )
        {
            die('Error: ' . $conn->error);
        }

        else
        {
            echo "Success";
        }
```

And this is my stored procedure:

```
$insertIntoUsers = "
CREATE PROCEDURE userInsert(unique_id VARCHAR(23), name VARCHAR(50), encrypted_password VARCHAR(80), email VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, encrypted_password,email) values(unique_id, name,encrypted_password,email);
END";
```

I want it to take four field but I get the following error when I try to sign up

```
Error: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE users.userInsert; expected 3, got 4
```

Anyone know whats causing this? Saying it only wants three arguments, but I have specified four?

Answer (score 0):

managed to sort it

I had the same procedure stored before with 3 arguments, when I added the fourth argument, it never updated, so I dropped the procedure first using:

```
drop procedure users.userInsert;
```

and ran the program again, everything worked then